# Django Rest Framework. How Retrieve works

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am fairly new to Django rest framework and I had a couple questions that would really clear up a lot of stuff for me.

I was looking at docs for simple CRUD generic views like ListAPIView, Retrieve... etc.

For my list view I created it like this:

```
class CourseListApiView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseListSerializer
```

Which makes sense because of the queryset returns Course.objects.all() so all the courses appear.

What I am not clear about is how the queryset in RetrieveApi works

```
class CourseRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseRetrieveSerializer
```

This is my retrieve view, it takes pk from my link and returns a corresponding course. What is unclear to me is why the queryset is Course.objects.all(), not a filtered query that gets the kwargs from the URL and filters my Courses. I tried it my way and got the same results, my view was:

```
class CourseRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = CourseRetrieveSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Course.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return queryset
```

This makes more sense since the queryset is Course.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')) instead of Course.objects.all() which to me doesn't make sense since I am filtering my courses by the pk in the URL

Hope my question made sense. Leave a comment if you need any clarification. I know the answer will be pretty obvious but I am very new to the framework

Answer (score 9):

You will have to go through the codebase of `rest_framework`. A function named `get_object` uses two class variables named `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` which have a default value of `pk` and `None` respectively.

Excerpt from the `GenericAPIView` in `rest_framework/generics.py`

```
def get_object(self):
    """
    Returns the object the view is displaying.

    You may want to override this if you need to provide non-standard
    queryset lookups.  Eg if objects are referenced using multiple
    keyword arguments in the url conf.
    """
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    # Perform the lookup filtering.
    lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field

    assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
        'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
        'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
        'attribute on the view correctly.' %
        (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
    )

    filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)

    # May raise a permission denied
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

    return obj
```

As you can see the `lookup_url_kwarg` is set to be equal to `lookup_field` if nothing is specified. If you change this value to a field of your requirement then the filter in `get_object_or_404` changes.

Now coming back to your issue, when you are specifying the filter manually with `url kwargs` you are not using the functionality provided by the `RetrieveAPIView`. Instead what you are doing is filtering out your result with `pk` from `url kwargs` in `get_queryset` and then sending that QuerySet result to `get_object` which will again do the same thing for you.